# Can we construct an infinite list that satisfies a given bit predicate?

Tags: list, haskell, predicate, bitstring

If we have a given predicate `p :: [Bool] -> Bool` that take an infinite list as parameter and return `True` or `False` based on some unknown conditions, and we have no idea what this predicate is.

Can we work out a function `f :: ([Bool] -> Bool) -> [Bool]` that take such predicate and return an infinite list l where `p l == True`, assuming that the predicate is satisfiable.

Comment: Reminds me of http://math.andrej.com/2007/09/28/seemingly-impossible-functional-programs/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can think of an infinite list `[Bool]` as being a binary number with the least significant bit first:

```
0 = repeat False
1 = True : repeat False
2 = False : True : repeat False
3 = True : True : repeat False
```

and so on to infinity.

So if you construct a function like this:

```
intToBools :: Integer -> [Bool]
```

then you can write

```
f p = head $ filter p $ map intToBools [0..]
```

Will this work for every predicate `p`? Well, if we restrict ourselves to total functions then the `p` must inspect a finite prefix of its argument, and if any finite prefix is acceptable then that prefix must be reached eventually.

If `p` is not total but can return `True` for at least one argument (e.g. the predicate "argument contains at least one `True`"), then this problem cannot be solved as written because we can't know if `p x` will ever terminate. However if `p` could be expressed as a state machine:

```
newtype BoolPredicate = BoolPredicate (Bool -> Either Bool BoolPredicate)
```

then you could enumerate every possible input by recursively applying `True` and `False` to the output of the previous step in a breadth-first search until you find `Left True`.

Comment: This computes an infinite list of (finite) lists that satisfy the predicate, not a single infinite list that satisfies the predicate.

Comment: No it doesn't. The outputs from `intToBools` are all infinite, its just that they all have a tail with an infinite list of `False` (so e.g. a list consisting of an infinite alternation of `True, False` will never be produced). But as long as `p` is total that doesn't matter.

Comment: Ah, missed that detail.